# How to display audio meter on an iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avaudiorecorder

I have an audio recorder and I was wondering if anyone has a code to show a audio meter (the bar that most of audio recorders have which shows the level of input audio).

Answer (score 4):

Apple's [SpeakHere](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html) example code includes a LevelView class which seems to be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: This apple sample code is anything but simple to implement it within your own project. Extremely confusing and needlessly complicated

Comment: Yeah. It is not simple at all. What it does pretty simple but code is so much confusing...

Comment: @SamB Can I use apple's SpeakHear example in my project?

Comment: The link is broken.. Can anyone share the level view class?

Comment: Looks like there's a copy of the SpeakHere example at https://github.com/robovm/apple-ios-samples/tree/master/SpeakHere

Answer (score 2):

Heres an example that calculates output and prints it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/dev/null"]; // Your audio save path

    NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0], AVSampleRateKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax], AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                          nil];

    NSError *error;

    recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error];

    if (recorder) {
        [recorder prepareToRecord];
        recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
        [recorder record];
        levelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.03 target: self selector: @selector(levelTimerCallback:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
    } 
}


 - (void)levelTimerCallback:(NSTimer *)timer {
    [recorder updateMeters];

    const double ALPHA = 0.05;
    double peakPowerForChannel = pow(10, (0.05 * [recorder peakPowerForChannel:0]));
    lowPassResults = ALPHA * peakPowerForChannel + (1.0 - ALPHA) * lowPassResults;
    NSLog(@"%f",(lowPassResults*100.0f));
}
```

Depending on the **lowPassResults** you can animate a view accordingly.

Comment: 'lowPassResults' is used uninitialized, is it iVar? What is initial value for it?