# ios - How to make an analog meter

Tags: xcode, meter

I want to make a basic analog meter (like a speedometer) for iOS that I can reuse for audio and other functions.. Could someone give me some starter points? Frameworks, samples, open source, etc.

Comment: This is similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5687349/1177191. Not analog, but maybe this concept will help.

Comment: Thanks. I know how to hook up the audio part.. I'm trying to figure how to make the speedometer graphics :)

Comment: I'm going to mark yours as the correct answer. It forced me to focus my thinking so that as soon as I looked for "Speedometer", I got this - which is perfect : http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/ios-tutorial-custom-speedometer-control/

Comment: So can you please write your comment as an answer so I can close this out. Thanks

Comment: I've done that. Glad you're on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5687349/1177191. Not analog, but maybe this concept will help.